# How to set absolute div over overflow hidden grandparent

Tags: css, overflow

I got an overflow hidden container (scrollable) and within a couple of tiles with custom dropdowns for better touch usability.

The problem: I can't get the dropdown list shown above the overflow hidden grandparent:

```
<div id="overflow">
<div class="tile">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
<div class="tile">
    <div class="absolute"></div>
</div>
</div>

#overflow{
    height: 190px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tile {
    clear: both;
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
    width: 180px;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid green;
    z-index: auto;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: -20px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: red;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/enmwmtw8/

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can't be achieved in this way. As whatever is in the overflow: hidden container can't be shown outside of it.

The only way to do this would be to place the dropdown outside the container